# CSS position absolute in inline elements

Tags: jquery, css, position, absolute

I am using this tutorial for image hover effect:
http://webdesignandsuch.com/create-overlay-on-image-hover-jquery-css3/

Last overlay is still always in line while image thumb is already in another line.

Here is screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUumO.jpg
Every thumb looks like this:

```
<a href="image.jpg">
    <span class="overlay"></span> <!-- this is position:absolute -->
    <img src="thumb.jpg">
</a>
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: share ur code ! or create [Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/)

Comment: what is the problem with the code

Comment: How to make every overlay span on img? Last span in line is out of a tag and I want to make it inside a tag. Code is exactly the same like in first link.

Comment: set position relative to the parrent and position absolute to the img then adjust using top,left that's all

Comment: @Parnav I tried - it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/XSgq4/

```
<div class="overlay">
    <a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com/">
        <img src="http://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/uploads/stackoverflow-logo-300.png" />
    </a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.overlay {
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
}
.overlay > a:hover:after {
    content:'';
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background:rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}
```

Or a span version: http://jsfiddle.net/XSgq4/1/

Comment: Two option, span is more compatible, :after is more clean.

Comment: Try to resize result: fiddle.jshell.net/D4zSM/1 I'm trying to make red overlay always on every grey img even when resizing browser.

Comment: That is another question then.

Comment: @TomChung this works perfect, thank you! This is exactly what I was trying to make. Thank you again!